# Does scapy support IEEE 802.1ad?

Tags: scapy, vlan

I've checked the latest Scapy sources and there isn't any 802.1AD support, yet I have seen Scapy scripts referencing Dot1AD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, 802.1ad support was imported into Scapy master on July 30, 2016. So you don't need to get scapy-com (no longer maintained) and can use the "regular" Scapy. The associated layer is `Dot1AD()`.

Answer (score 1):

After some additional searching it turns out that `Scapy community` has created a fork of Scapy which supports 802.1AD.  Here is a [link](http://hg.secdev.org/scapy-com).  Scripts referencing `Dot1AD` use the `scapy-com` module.

Comment: Scapy-Comunity was a fork used as a buffer between open contributions and releases, in the early stages of scapy (when github did not even exist)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

`>>> packet = Ether(src='94:c6:91:1c:68:c3',dst='94:c6:91:1c:68:1d')`

Then add a 802.1ad layer:

`packet = packet/Dot1AD(vlan=20)`

Then display the packet:

```
>>> packet.show()
###[ Ethernet ]### 
  dst= 94:c6:91:1c:68:1d
  src= 94:c6:91:1c:68:c3
  type= n_802_AD
###[ 802_1AD ]### 
     prio= 0
     id= 0
     vlan= 20
     type= 0x0
```